# Neural network error derivation Sigmoid

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation, sigmoid

In my book about AI is written that the error function is (target-output)^2

d=Delta

W=weight

O=Output

T=target

dE/Wa = dE/dOk * dOk/dWa

dE/dWa = -2*(Tk-Ok)*dOk/dWa. //Where comes this minus from?

So derivation must be 2*(target-Output). I do not understand where the minus comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are forgetting to take the derivative of the inside as well.  Because the derivative is a function of the output.  Therefore, you also have to take the derivative of the inside "-output", which we can imagine as "-x".  And the derivative is simply -1.

Therefore, the function is actually (target - output)(-1)(2) where the (-1) is from the (-output)'s derivative and (2) is from the power.

This website describes some basic examples of this derivative:

https://www.intmath.com/differentiation/7-derivative-powers-of-function.php

EDIT: Traditionally, if you are simply doing backpropagation, you are taking the gradients as a function of J, so there actually should not be a negative sign there.  The only time for the negative sign would be if the derivative was taken as a function of the output. But I will look into this further.